# "[kubelet-check]" kubelet not running when: kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes, debian-buster, containerd

When the command: kubeadm init, is commited eventually this error pops up:

```
[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http://localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.
```

After looking at the journalctl -xeu kubelet, it seems like containerd is not working right. However, containerd is active and running.

Here is the first error in journalctl -xeu kubelet log:

```
vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://X.X.X.X:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp X.X.X.X:6443: connect: connection refused vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://X.X.X.X:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp X.X.X.X:6443: connect: connection refused
```